# Muscle or Muscles

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Every time I look up anything fitness related I get confused between 'muscle' and 'muscles.' Do we say:

1. How to build muscle. - here I'm talking about all the muscles in my body but some pages still use muscle.
2. How to grow your chest muscle.- Do we say 'muscles' or 'muscle' here? As far as I know chest is considered a single muscle.

Bodybuilders are now drinking breast milk to build **muscle**:
https://www.timesnownews.com/health/article/bodybuilders-are-now-drinking-breast-milk-to-build-muscle-is-it-safe-for-adults/648409

Some men are now drinking breastmilk to build **muscles**:
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/health-fitness/health-news/shocking-some-men-are-now-drinking-breastmilk-to-build-muscles/articleshow/77928967.cms

Answer (score 2):

For 1., either *muscle* or *muscles* can be used. The singular form means muscle in general. Muscle in general, in a person's body, consists of individual muscles, so either term works.

For 2., there is no single muscle known as the chest muscle. People's chests have lots of muscles. Here, it would be better to use the plural, because "your chest muscle" might lead people to think that it is actually a unique muscle.

Comment: You can nevertheless refer to just one of many chest muscles by presenting its name.

Comment: Quite. My pecs are sore today.

Comment: I see. Would it be correct to say "His muscle is very thick but lean" to mean his all his muscles in general? Or should I say "His muscles are very thick but lean?"

Comment: "Thick but lean" would be an unusual description, either way. You could say "His muscles are well-developed.", If you mean muscle in general, you might say "His musculature is well-developed."

Comment: So you suggest plural. I've heard some people say- "I need some muscle/ Time to build some muscle." Should it be 'some muscles?'

Comment: I suggested plural if you've specified "chest", since there isn't a single chest muscle. In general, I think "building muscle" is better. Speaking of individual muscles, like pectorals, for example, I would say 'build up my pectoral muscles", referring to increasing the strength of individual muscles. I think usage is very diverse. You might try searching Google ngram viewer to check the frequency of individual phrases.